# XSL If Contains

Tags: xml, xslt

I’m working on an XSL file that will (among many other things) display a button if the corresponding XML file contains a certain string.  I seem to be having an issue where I get the button to display all the time (even when the XML file doesn’t contain the value I want) or never (even when the XML file does contain the value.  The portion of the XML file I'm concerned with is:

```
<sp_stList>
<sp_st>
<st_num>1234</st_num>
<feanme>FAKE</feanme>
<featyp>ST</featyp>
<dirsuf></dirsuf>
<dirpre></dirpre>
<lv_apt></lv_apt>
<mun>VAN</mun>
<msgs>
<msg filename="File.pdf">d:\folder1\fild.pdf</msg>
</msgs>
<spst_poly>0</spst_poly>
<mes_switch>X</mes_switch>
<cdts>20120103161202PS</cdts>
</sp_st>
</sp_stList>
```

What should happen is that when `<mes_switch>` contains an X then the button should be displayed.  If it is blank or has another character in it then it should not display the button.

The code I have tried is:

```
<a name="Info"></a>
    <xsl:if "contains(sp_stList/sp_st/mes_switch, 'X'))">
        <a href="#SpSt" style="color:orange" t:id="Spec_Sit_hdr">
            <img border="0" src="./file.jpg"></img>
        </a>
    </xsl:if>
```

For some reason this doesn't see to work.  Any help you could provide would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
<xsl:if "contains(sp_stList/sp_st/mes_switch, 'X'))">
```

**This is syntactically illegal XML (and therefore alo syntactically illegal XSLT code:**

1. The boolean expression to be evaluated must be specified in a `test` attribute -- no such attribute is present.
2. There is a right parenthesis that has no corresponding left parenthesis.

**Solution**: Correcting just those two problems leads to working code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <a name="Info"></a>
        <xsl:if test="contains(sp_stList/sp_st/mes_switch, 'X')">
            <a href="#SpSt" style="color:orange" id="Spec_Sit_hdr">
                <img border="0" src="./file.jpg"></img>
            </a>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<sp_stList>
    <sp_st>
        <st_num>1234</st_num>
        <feanme>FAKE</feanme>
        <featyp>ST</featyp>
        <dirsuf></dirsuf>
        <dirpre></dirpre>
        <lv_apt></lv_apt>
        <mun>VAN</mun>
        <msgs>
            <msg filename="File.pdf">d:\folder1\fild.pdf</msg>
        </msgs>
        <spst_poly>0</spst_poly>
        <mes_switch>X</mes_switch>
        <cdts>20120103161202PS</cdts>
    </sp_st>
</sp_stList>
```

**the wanted correct result is produced:**

```
<a name="Info"/>
<a href="#SpSt" style="color:orange" id="Spec_Sit_hdr">
   <img border="0" src="./file.jpg"/>
</a>
```

Comment: Just to add to Dimitre's answer, I suspect you want to test "equals" rather than "contains". Just because you think "element contains value" in English doesn't mean you need the contains() function.

Comment: Thanks to you both.  I have tried modifying the content as listed about however now the system won't process the XML file at all.  When I click to the page where the formatted XML should be it shows only the XSL code.

Comment: @user1424931: Most probably you are running *not* exactly the same transformation on *not* exactly the same source XML document. I always test that the solutions I give in my answers are running OK and producing exactly the result that I provide -- in fact I copy and paste the result of the transformation into the answer. Therefore, you need to run the exact transformation from this answer on the exact source XML document from this answer -- you will get the same result. Then, it is clear that you have additional problems -- but the one you have been asking for is completely solved.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe don't have two closing brackets, would be a start. Also using:

test=contains(...

is better than just using:

contains(...

You are less likely to run into problems